# If $|G|=$pn,with $p>n$, p prime and $H\leq G $ of order p then $H\unlhd G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, sylow-theory

Note that the subgroup $H$ assures the uniqueness of the given group $G$ of order $pn$ with $p>n$,in other words,if there were another subgroup $K\leq G$ of order $p$ then $K=H$.

For every $a \in G,$ one has $aHa^{-1}\leq G$ and $|aHa^{-1}|=p=|H|$

,so by the fact mentioned above we must have $aHa^{-1}=H$ ,for each $a\in G$.Then $H\unlhd G.$

So, now if there were another different subgroup $K\leq G$ from $H$ with order p.By counting formula we have
$$pn=|G|\geq |HK|=\frac{|H||K|}{|H\cap K|}=\frac{p^2}{|H\cap K|}$$
Then $|H\,\cap K|\neq1$ ,otherwise we yields a contradicton by above counting formula.

So if $H\,\cap K=K$ then $K\subseteq H,$a contradiction since $H$ and $K$ are distinct.

So if $H\,\cap K=H$ then $H\subseteq K,$a contradiction the reason is the same as above.

Is there anyone has different way to solve this question ?
 Any comment will be considered and thanks for taking the time to read my proof.

Comment: The assertion in your first paragraph is the key fact, but you simply stated it without proof.

Comment: @Bungo thanks for remind.I edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Sylow's third theorem, the number of conjugates of $P$ satisfies
$m\equiv1\pmod p$. But $m\mid n$ and $n<p$. Thus $m=1$.

Comment: This is a quite short and correct point of this problem.

Comment: Indeed. Sylow's theorems reduce group theoretic problems into basic arithmetic.